# Which scholars are respected by Quranists?

Tags: islamic-scholar, quran-only

Most of the information I find about Qur'an-only versions of Islam tend to be from some random webpage.  Some examples are:

- [Quran-Islam.org](http://www.quran-islam.org/).  Some of the articles (possibly all) are attributed to someone known as "A. Muhammad".
- [Free-Minds.org](https://www.free-minds.org/).  Some articles here are attributed to Layth Al-Shaiban who has a co-translation of the Qur'an ([amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0979671507)).
- [QuranMessage.com](http://quransmessage.com/) by Joseph A. Islam.

Looking at random articles from these sites, aside from the Qur'an, the only references I found were to other pages on their respective sites; they don't even cite each other.  It's hard to tell, therefore, which scholarly opinion Quranists value.

**Question**: Which scholars are respected by Quranists?

Comment: The whole point of Quranism is to place your trust only in the Quran and do away with the 1400 years of scholarly tradition before it as an accident of history, not authoritative interpretation. I'd be surprised if they respected any kind of scholarly tradition.

Comment: I don't believe they do respect any traditional scholars. For instance The Quran-Islam.org seems to use  the translation of "Dr. Rashad Khalifa". They explain it to be: " It is one of the most sincere English translations of the Quran. Dr. Khalifa's translation does not interpret the Quran from a 'hadith and sunna' perspective and thus it presents the pure message of the Quran." In this translation, he has translated himself to be the a prophet, in sura yasin: "[36:3] Most assuredly, you (Rashad) are one of the messengers. "- All traditional scholars would condemn this.

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult to answer because Qur'an-only Muslims have different opinions about scholars.  Some outright reject any material outside of the Qur'an, deferring to one's God-given logic, while others allow outside material to varying degrees.

Two prominent examples are:

1. [Ahmed Subhi Mansour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahmed_Subhy_Mansour), who Wikipedia says "founded the small Egyptian Quranists sect", could be regarded as a scholar.  However, he writes (sourced from [here](http://www.ahl-alquran.com/English/show_article.php?main_id=6001)):

   > So long as God is sufficient enough for the Believer as a lord, then so too is the Book of God sufficient enough for guidance and legislation ...

   This undermines the necessity of his own authority.
2. [Rashad Khalifa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashad_Khalifa), who may not necessarily be accurately described as a scholar, published a translation of the Qur'an ([pdf](http://www.quranalone.com/media/quran-english.pdf)) with extensive footnoting which may be regarded as tafsir.  In reference to this, a user of the Qur'an-only [free-minds.org forum](https://free-minds.org/forum/index.php?topic=9598759.10) explains the situation as:

   > **Some of us might accept the tafsir of Rashad, but not all.**  I think there's more of us that prefers to study by ourselves and develop our own tafsir.

   Here we see a difference in attitudes among Qur'an-only Muslims.

Comment: This answer is mainly correct, but I would add that of the two you mentioned above, Ahmed Mansour is by far the closest to a Quranist "scholar" in that he was a history professor in Egypt and has written many books in the history of Islam, from which he derived his ideas about Quranism, and he is also the head of a "Quranist Society" which meets regularly and he can be said to have followers. One could also mention the owner/ founder of the free-minds.org society quoted above, Layth Shaiban, a Saudi citizen, who has written a translation of the Quran (in cooperation with others, I believe).

Comment: Rashad Khalifa is generally regarded as the first proponent of the "number 19 miracle" of the Quran, based on which he derived the idea of rejecting the tradition of hadeeths. However he developed his rejection of hadeeths further based on some of them apparently contradicting the Quran. Mansour and Khalifa met prior to the latter's death by murder (for his beliefs), at which time Mansour rejected Khalifa's claim (developed later) that he himself was a messenger, and a number of other erroneous beliefs (such as there being a verse "injected" in the Quran. For that, most Quranists rejected him.

Answer (score 1):

As a quranist muslim i have a lot of respect for ghamdi(who has far as i know is not quranist). That being said being human we are all fallible. I listen to different scholars from different sects and try to follow the most reasonable logical explanations.